# setup home webserver for grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails, webserver, router, portforwarding

I have developed an application in Grails and I want to setup a simple webserver to let the application be reached over the net. My machine has Ubuntu OS.
I've just installed tomcat server, noip (with DUC) for addressing and I've given a static address into my lan and done port forwarding for router  DSL-2640R for port 8080.
In LAN everything works well, but the app is not accessible from outside. I can access to public address given to noip.com (or the related URL created), but if I add the 8080 port, it is unreachable.
Anyone has a suggestion? I hope the question is clear.

Comment: What is the  value of grails.serverURL config? How you access/reach your application from LAN? How you try access/reach your application from inet? Did you check firewall on your OS ? What is the result of <code>telnet yourHost/IP  8080 </code>?

Comment: I access my application in LAN using local_ip_of_machine:8080/appName. Using noip.com, I set up an host that links a global URL with local address of my LAN (that I can see using whatismyip.com website). In Ubuntu OS I have no firewall. If I perform the telnet with global_ip 8080 the telnet not answer. If I do only telnet global_ip (without any port) the telnet works. What about grails.serverURL?

Comment: I guess you are sending request from inet (via noip.com) to port 80 but your applicatoin/tomcat is responding to 8080 port.
Change tomcat port to 80 and port in config grails.serverURL.

Comment: By now my grails.serverURL in production section of config file is commented...do I need to uncomment it and set it as grails.serverURL = "urlGivenByNoIp:80" ?

Comment: I've changed the port to 80 in Tomcat. Now my application does not work either locally. I think it is not possible to give 80 port to Tomcat.

Comment: yes, Tomcat can run on port 80, on a linux system you will need to be root to start it as all ports less than 1024 are considered privileged. Once changing tomcat to use 80 , you can access the app locally  with the regular url without the :portNumber , ie,  http://localhost/myGrailsApp

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a network/firewall/ISP issue. 
Tomcat can definitely run grails as a war without issues on port 80 (the default http port)

Comment: Using the 8080 port, in my LAN I cannot access to URL given by noip.com, but from outside (I've used my smartphone 3G connection) everything works well...